# Is it possible to associate nodes from two different stores?

Tags: java, alfresco

I have a child association in spacesStore node and trying to associate spacesStore node with node from version2store. During save I am getting error  :   `org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.InvalidNodeRefException: Node does not exist: versionStore://version2Store/5e78603d-8422-441d-9f24-85fcadf625e9(null).`   
I checked and found that target assoc node exists in version2store
Is it possible to associate nodes from two different stores ?

Comment: Are you sure the nodeRef is correct? shouldnt it be workspace://version2Store/5e78603d-8422-441d-9f24-85fcadf625e9 ?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. There is no broblem to find node in node browser. There is a code to log `throw new InvalidNodeRefException("Node does not exist: " + nodeRef + "(" + nodeStatus + ")", nodeRef);` if you are confused by the presence of "(null)"

Comment: I meant workspace:// as prefix instead of versionStore://

Comment: Yes! You are right, thx!
Everything worked well after the change versionStore:// to workspace://.